# How can I resize maps to fill the plot window?

Tags: r, plot

I started using R's `map()` function to plot maps. I noticed that when I resize the plot window, the image does not scale to fill the window. How can I get the map image to automatically resize bigger or smaller, depending on how big I drag my window?

I am using R version 3.0.2 on MacOS.

For example, here is a map where I've dragged the plot window smaller and bigger. Notice that the map image's size does not change.

```
library(maps)
map("state")
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

On the other hand, the usual `plot()` command **does** resize the graphic to fit the window.

```
plot(1:100, 201:300)
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You could specify the size of the plot window prior to the plot call eg dev.new(width=3,height=3)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It takes a bit of work, but by converting the `maps` object to a `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame`, and then `spplot()`'ing that, you can get a dynamically resizing map.

FWIW, I suspect this works better because `spplot()` is based on **grid** (via **lattice**), and the grid graphical system supports much more sophisticated ways of handling dimensions within plot objects than does R's base graphical system.

```
library(maps)
library(maptools)  ## For map2SpatialPolygons()

## Convert data from a "maps" object to a "SpatialPolygonsDataFrame" object
mp <- map("state", fill = TRUE, plot = FALSE)
SP <- map2SpatialPolygons(mp, IDs = mp$names, 
                          proj4string = CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"))
DATA <- data.frame(seq_len(length(SP)), row.names = names(SP))
SPDF <- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(SP, data = DATA)

## Plot it
spplot(SPDF, col.regions = "transparent", colorkey = FALSE,
       par.settings = list(axis.line = list(col = "transparent")))
```

Here are a couple of screenshots to show that it works:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks. That seems like a lot of work for such a simple problem.

Comment: You're welcome. It is a bit of work, but then again I've done most of it for you ;). If you wrap most of the code above in a function, calling it could be as easy as doing something like `plotMap2SPDF(mp)`.

Comment: Hmm. Looks like one needs the map() call to include `fill=T`. Otherwise, you get an error. `Error in map2SpatialPolygons(mp, IDs = mp$names, proj4string = CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")) : map and IDs differ in length`

Comment: @stackoverflowuser2010 -- Yep, that's correct. To understand why, see paragraph two in the `Value` section of `?map`.

Answer (score 3):

I note that Josh has provided an acceptable solution to the problem, but it might be useful to understand *why* `map()` has the behaviour you describe. Essentially it comes down to `map()` setting the size of the *plotting region* based on the current size & aspect ratio of the device (the *figure region* more specifically) at draw time.

As such, one solution, without converting to another format, as Josh nicely demonstrates, is just to redraw the map **after** you've rescaled the device to the desired size. You could avoid some guesswork by doing a couple of computations based on the aspect ratio of `par("usr")` and then set the device to a width that is compatible with that aspect ratio.

Probably more hassle than @Josh's solution, but it does explain the behaviour. A more detailed description of the issue is given below.

---

The reason that the drawn map doesn't "fill" the device (up to the specified margins) is due to the code in `map()` setting the size of the plotting region to have a particular aspect ratio based on the size of the device etc. The resulting plotting region is the sized such that it fits within the device, but preserves the correct aspect ratio so may not entirely fill it.

The key section of code is this:

```
        else {
            par(mar = mar)
            p <- par("fin") - as.vector(matrix(c(0, 1, 1, 
              0, 0, 1, 1, 0), nrow = 2) %*% par("mai"))
            par(pin = p)
            p <- par("pin")
            p <- d * min(p/d)
            par(pin = p)
            d <- d * myborder + ((p/min(p/d) - d)/2)/aspect
            usr <- c(xrange, yrange) + rep(c(-1, 1), 2) * 
              rep(d, c(2, 2))
            par(usr = usr)
        }
```

with `d` defined slightly earlier as:

```
        d <- c(diff(xrange), diff(yrange)) * (1 + 2 * myborder) * 
            aspect
```

(for the example you give). The second line of the `else` branch is getting the current size of the figure region in inches. The figure region is the size on the device of the region containing the margins and the plot region but *not* any outer margin. In effect, if there is no outer margin active, this code is grabbing the size of the device (and makes an adjustment). This result is then use to set the size of the plotting region, which gets updated.

The intention seems to be to take the size of the current figure region, and use that to update the region into which the map is drawn. The size of that plotting region is in that sense controlled via the aspect ratio of the device; if you start with a wide but short window, then the computed plotting region will not need to use all the available width (if it did the aspect ratio would be wrong) and hence the plotting region is set to a size smaller than the available space.

As to why this doesn't update when you resize the window, well that is because at draw-time the size of the plotting region is set *absolutely* in **inches**. If you resize the device, the size of the plotting region remains the same and hence the map gets cropped if you shrink the device sufficiently, or uses less and less of the device space if you enlarge the device.

Comment: Do you know of any plotting functions based on base graphics that dynamically resize the figure region while maintaining its aspect? I'm trying to think of any, but am drawing a blank. If there are any, it'd be interesting to see how they accomplish that. (**grid** *ultimately* does this via the `respect=` argument to  `grid:::grid.layout()`.)

Comment: I was wondering whether setting the `asp` parameter might not have been a better way to solve this for `map()` but haven't thought about it much to be honest - I was just intrigued why the plot wasn't rescaling.

Comment: But is there an `asp` parameter for base graphics? (I kind of thought there was, but don't see it in `?par`.)

Comment: @JoshO'Brien See `?plot.window`, so sorry, not a parameter (in sense of `?par`, but a settable argument that is like the other three-letter-parameters my mind conflated them.

Comment: Thanks. FTR, I wasn't being legalistic about definition of a "parameter". I just couldn't figure out why I had thought there was an `asp`, but couldn't find it. And yes, hardwiring `fin` does *seem* like a regrettable design decision.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien No, it was *me* that was mis-remembering `asp` as a `?par` parameter. If you hadn't mentioned it wasn't in `?par` I'd still be thinking that it was one.

Comment: Unfortunately, `asp` doesn't seem like it'll help. The problem is that, while it fixes the relative lengths of x- and y- units, it redefines the interpretation of supplied `xlim` and `ylim` args. (To see how it interprets them, try this `plot(1:10, xlim=c(1,10), ylim=c(1,10), asp=2)`, then resize the plotting window in different ways and reset xlim and/or ylim. This just may be a task for which base graphics isn't well (or at all?) suited. Section 2 of [this Deepayan Sarkar article](http://www.r-project.org/conferences/DSC-2003/Proceedings/Sarkar.pdf) touches on +/- the same topic..

Comment: @JoshO'Brien Right; though given the axis limits, `asp` is already set regardless of what value you ask for. In that system you only need 2 of the 3 parameters, you can't set all three. I can see why they want the x-y limits set as that allows you to specify the region of interest in coordinates. The real issue, as alluded to in the section of Deepayan's article is the lack of relative sizes for margins, plot and figure regions etc. It is the hard setting of the plot region in `map()` in absolute terms that causes the plot not to resize with the device.

Comment: OK, thanks. I think that helps. IIUC, the upshot is that **maps**' authors *could* have used `asp` to plot aspect-respecting resizable maps, but the lengths of the axes plotted around those mapped regions would *not* have kept a constant ratio. Just for the record, here's how specify an aspect respecting viewport using **grid**: `grid.show.layout(grid.layout(1,1,respect=TRUE, widths=1.3, heights=1))`.

Comment: Exactly @JoshO'Brien, I can see it as a design decision within the limits of base graphics. grid is so much more flexible, but with that comes a good deal more complexity, complexity that I'm still getting to grips with.